# Call web service with different time interval?

Tags: android, timer, rx-java, rx-android

I am new in Rx android.i am trying to call web service in different time interval.

call Api 4 hours  every 1 minutes for 30 minutes, then every 5 minutes for 3 hours and 30 minutes

is it possible to do with Rx android.if possible let me know how to do this?

```
 Observable.interval(1,TimeUnit.MINUTES).takeWhile(Observable.timer(30,TimeUnit.MINUTES).concatWith(Observable.interval(5,TimeUnit.MINUTES).takeWhile(Observable.timer(30,TimeUnit.MINUTES).flatMap(new Func1<Long, Observable<?>>() {
            @Override
            public Observable<?> call(Long aLong) {
                return null;
            }
        }).subscribe((new Observer<Object>() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted() {
                Log.e("working", "onCompleted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e("working", "onComThrowablepleted");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(Object o) {
                Log.e("working", "onNext");

            }
        });
        ))
```

Comment: using multiple timer we can do this.i need to know is it possible with Rx android..

Comment: The answer is: Yes. It's possible. Have you tried **anything**?

Comment: No,i am new in rx android ..let me know any tutorial or Example project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `interval`, `takeUntil`, `timer` and `concatWith` : The idea is to use `interval` and stop it after 30 minutes, then use another `interval`.

```
 // 1 events per minutes
 Observable.interval(1, MINUTES)
           // and stop it after 30 minutes
           .takeUntil(Observable.timer(30, MINUTES))
           // then 1 events per 5 minutes, and stop it after 30 minutes
           .concatWith(Observable.interval(5, MINUTES).takeUntil(Observable.timer(30, MINUTES)))
           // perform webservice call
           .flatMap(time -> webservice.call())
           .subscribe();
```

Comment: let me know more explanation about this.

Comment: i tried this.but i think i am missing some think.its not properly closed braces

Comment: The method takeWhile(Func1<? super Long,Boolean>) in the type Observable<Long> is not applicable for the arguments (Observable<Long>)

Comment: because I wrote takeUntil in the text but use takeWhile in the code. another mistake.